# If Else Conditions Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to redirect based on countries

after detecting country I want to detect is that user from mobile or desktop

and then redirect

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {

    if (location.country_code == 'PH' || location.country_code == 'IN') {
        top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    } else if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

    } else {
        top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    }
 });
```

This isn't working

Comment: `if/elseif/else` statement will let your code run only through one of them, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {

        if (location.country_code == 'PH' || location.country_code == 'IN') { 
                 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                     top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx?type=mobile';//mobile
                  } else {
                     top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx?type=desktop';//desktop
                 }
        } else{
              top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';// other country
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function (location) {

    if (location.country_code == 'PH' || location.country_code == 'IN') {
        top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
        if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {} else {
            top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        }
    } else {
        //code for other countries 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {

if (location.country_code == 'PH' || location.country_code == 'IN') {
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       top.location.href = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
    } else {
       top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    }
} else {
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       top.location.href = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzz';
    } else {
       top.location.href = 'ttttttttttttt';
    }
}
});
```